# Могу ли я показывать в своем приложении свою собственную баннерную рекламу?

Tags: android, ios

У меня есть мобильное приложение. Могу ли я показывать в своем приложении свою собственную баннерную рекламу? Без iAd, admob и т.д.

Comment: Да. Но мне нужно ещё 27 символов для отправки ответа.

Answer (score 6):

Вопрос неоднозначный. Зависит от политики маркета, в котором вы будете публиковать свое приложение.

Для Google Play существуют определенные правила в отношении рекламы размещаемой в приложении. [Втыкать сюда](https://play.google.com/intl/ru_ALL/about/monetization-ads/ads/) - правила несложные.

Если же речь идет о каком-нибудь blackmart - то там вообще никаких правил нет.

Comment: Планирую размещать на play market и app store

Comment: Тогда читайте первоисточники - там все написано - чего можно, а чего нельзя